# wxDataViewModel: What is it and how do i use it?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

i read the documentation http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_data_view_model.html several times but it hardly answers any questions. Maybe i'm confused as to the function of this class?

so i riddle you this:

- Is this a View Model as we know from MVVM?
- How do you implement a derivative?
- How do you set data in the containing wxDataViewListCtrl?
- Is this the right/recommended way to make a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name subtly hints, `wxDataViewModel` is indeed the model in the usual MVC design (while `wxDataViewCtrl` is both the view and the controller).

You can see a couple of examples of custom models in the [dataview sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/dataview/mymodels.h).

Notice that `wxDataViewListCtrl` is mostly a compatibility class made for transitioning the code using `wxListCtrl` to `wxDataViewCtrl` and it already defines its own trivial list model. I don't recommend using it unless this is exactly what you need.